# Create order actions from custom fields woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order

I am using Custom Order Fields Plugin in Woocommerece:
I am using for eg Call status as a custom order field here which have multiple options like Positive, Call Not Picked, Pending, Wrong Number, Busy, etc. Check the screenshot below:

[image: Custom Order Fields]

Now below screenshot is of my Orders Page where you can see these custom fields (Call Status)

[image]

Now these Call Status are all showing Pending. Whenever I call a customer I will change these status accordingly. For that I need to go to that particular order page and change it from there. Below is the screenshot of an order page where you can see the dropdown of all call status.

[image]

I can select the call status from here and update the order. Now this process is too lengthy as everytime I need to open the Order page and update it, I usually takes 70-80 calls per day which makes it time consuming for me to update status for each order.

Kindly suggest me a way where in I can change these status directly from order page, something like the order status can be changed from processing to shipped using the Action button on Order Page. I need a way something that can either add all these call status to order actions or something alternative so that I don't need to open each order individaully and update it

Comment: It sounds like you've got the right idea, yes: build a way to update these from the action button on the order page. Unless the custom order fields plugin supports this already though (and if you can't find another plugin that adds it for you already) I'd guess you'd have to write this yourself.

Comment: @Rup can you suggest me some plugins or any developer who can build this for me as I dont know coding, your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm not an expert on WooCommerce.